# Microsoft visual studio community 2015 blocked issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image: Here's my screenshot of my proble]

I've got message that "Microsoft visual studio community 2015 setup blocked" because I'm currently installed "Microsoft visual studio professional 2015" before but I've checked I'm not found any thing related to "Microsoft visual studio professional 2015" and I'v fully uninstalled  so, what can I do to solve it please !!!

Comment: I think you are in the wrong place, try the correct stack

Comment: Preferrably you should ask this at the [su].